# not able to execute the named functions that are also refereed

Tags: javascript

i'm learning about functions. i'm confused in one scenario.
suppose i have three functions

```
<script>
var fnRef = function() { 
  console.log("i'm function with no name but refered to fnRef"); 
}; 

var funRef2 = function test() {
  console.log("im test reffered to funRef2");
};

function test2() {
  console.log("i'm test2 named function")
};
</script>
```

`fnRef`, `fnref2` and `test2` will be assigned to window as a property as `fnRef` and `fnRef2` are variable and `test2` is named function that act as variable.
but why `test2` is not assigned to the global object(window) when refered by `funref2`? and why i'm not able to execute `test();` can someone tell me what is happening in detail.

Comment: you assigned the function test() to the var funRef2 scope. it's only available to that object. to call it you must use:

funRef2();

Comment: You definitely want to read https://kangax.github.io/nfe/ .

Answer (score 4):

The [named function expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/function#Named_function_expression) is useful so you can access the function inside it's own scope without using `arguments.callee`, and it also makes it easier when debugging as the name can be seen in stack traces, breakpoints etc.

This name is then local only to the function bodys scope, meaning

```
var test1 = function test2() {

   if (something) test2(); // available in this scope only

}

test2(); // not here
```

You can't call the function by it's name, only by the variable it's assigned to, as the functions name is limited to the functions scope when it's a function expression.

When defining a [function **declaration**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/function), the name is assigned to the current scope, and hoisted, so this

```
var bar = test();

function test() { return 'foo'; }
```

is more or less turned into this

```
var test = function() { return 'foo'; }

var bar = test();
```

Comment: i'm lil confused. i have read about hoisting. but your last example made me confuse.Can u tell me how function declaration gets hoisted. is it also converted into var example - 
    `<script>-----some code --toHost();
-------some code---
function toHost(){}
-----some code ----
</script>`
gets turn into 
`<script>
 var toHost;
---some code --
toHost(); // *error as toHost not function*
--some code --
toHost = function(){}
-- some Code --
</script>`
i know same thing happens in function expression,how toHost gets attach to global scope? i'm i right? is that what happens behing the scene?